# Pyrebase4 error cannot import name 'gaecontrib'

Tags: python, pyrebase, python-requests-toolbelt

I have been trying to install `pyrebase4` using `pip install pyrebase4` but when ran it throws below error

`"C:\Users\ChodDungaTujheMadhadchod\anaconda3\envs\sam_upgraded\lib\site-packages\requests_toolbelt\adapters\appengine.py", line 42, in <module> from .._compat import gaecontrib ImportError: cannot import name 'gaecontrib' from 'requests_toolbelt._compat'`

As I see the error direct directly to `requests_toolbelt` , but I cannot figure out the possible way to fix it, I tried upgrading to latest version as which is `requests-toolbelt==1.0.0` . So is there any way to fix it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay so what I found that the latest `requests-toolbelt 1.0.1` is currently throwing this issue. So downgrading it to next previous version `requests-toolbelt==0.10.1` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

My reply is a little late, but I discovered a another way to solve this error. This error, such you sayd, is something associated with the version. You can read [this github issue](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/618) that sayd:

> We claim urllib3 works with AppEngine but looks like it's broken today (as of a few months ago). Nobody on our core team uses AppEngine, so maintaining support for it has been a substantial drain.

It means that the urllib3, requests and requests-toolbelt actualy don't have suport from AppEngine, and the pyrebase import this dependencies to have compatibility. If you want to solve without loss the new atualizations, you can remove from the pyrebase file these lines:

```
19 - from requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.appengine import is_appengine_sandbox
20 - from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
```

And replace this line:

```
# 82 - adapter = appengine.AppEngineAdapter(max_retries=3)
82 - raise Exception('Appengine is not supported by pyrebase.')
```

You will need to have a way to discover if is a appengine, what `is_appengine_sandbox` did. So in the firsts lines you paste this function:

```
def is_appengine_sandbox():
    appengine_runtime = 'APPENGINE_RUNTIME' in os.environ
    is_local_appengine = (appengine_runtime and 'Development/' in os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'])
    is_prod_appengine = (appengine_runtime and 'Google App Engine/' in os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
                         and not is_prod_appengine_mvms)
    is_prod_appengine_mvms = os.environ.get('GAE_VM', False) == 'true'
    return (is_local_appengine or is_prod_appengine or is_prod_appengine_mvms) and not is_prod_appengine_mvms
```

It's the static def from `is_appengine_sandbox`

It's a temporary solution, maybe somebody with more experience in AppEngine will create a updated version from this, that accept AppEngine support.

**OBS**: If you can downgrade, will be better. It's answer is only if you need the newest libraries.